# Bash: Get filenames from names.txt and assign it to files in a folder

Tags: bash

So I have a a folder with the names of the files like so:

```
01
02
03
04
05
...
```

What I wanna do is create a bash script that looks in a another document in the same folder (i.e. names.txt), and assigns the files names, based on the text document. So if the 'names.txt' looks like this:

```
name1
name2
name3
...
```

I would like a bash script that can assign 'name1' to the file that is currently named '01' in the folder.

I'm still quite new to bash scripting, so any help would be appreciated. I am open to questions if something needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` to lign up ls (stdin) and the names file (in this case from the parent directory), and then iterate with a while loop reading the result line by line, over the list and do your thing:

```
ls ?? | sort -n | paste - ../names.txt | while read a b; do mv "$a" "$b"; done
```

This asumes that the filenames have no special char and that the number is exactly the count in the names file.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but when I do that it just says 

"mv: Cannot stat 'name1': No such file or directory"

Any idea why that might be?

Comment: yes, the names and minus had wrong order in paste, fixed now.

Comment: Almost working. Just like in another solution I tried, it adds an '/r' to the end of line, making bash think that it has to move the file to a subdirectory. You can see it here: http://i.imgur.com/zQIErJ4.png

Comment: You need to convert your names.txt file to unix file endings first.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea there was a difference between windows and unix file endings. Much to learn! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this script
Note: Take a backup of your folder before testing this.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ls -I names.txt -I rename.txt -I *.sh > rename.txt
    paste rename.txt names.txt | column -s $'\t' -t > rename_rules.txt
    eval "$(sed 's/^/mv /g' rename_rules.txt )"
    #rm rename.txt rename_rules.txt
```

This worked for me. Please find all the steps below.

```
$ touch 01 02 03 04 05

$ vim names.txt

$ cat names.txt
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5

$ ls
01  02  03  04  05  main.sh  names.txt

$ cat main.sh 
#!/bin/bash
ls -I names.txt -I rename.txt -I *.sh > rename.txt
paste rename.txt names.txt | column -s $'\t' -t > rename_rules.txt
eval "$(sed 's/^/mv /g' rename_rules.txt )"
exit 0;
#rm rename.txt rename_rules.txt

$ sh main.sh

$ ls
main.sh  name1  name2  name3  name4  name5  names.txt  rename.txt rename_rules.txt

$ cat rename_rules.txt
01  name1
02  name2 
03  name3
04  name4
05  name5
```

Can you share your actual filenames and names.txt contents so that we can debug?

Comment: Your solution is almost perfect. The only thing wrong is that for some reason, when getting to the eval command, it adds an '/r' at the end, making the bash thing it has to move the file called 'name1/r', which results in it saying "Cannot move to a subdirectory of itself.". Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for f in [0-9]*; do
  grep -q name"${f#0}" names.txt && mv "$f" name"${f#0}"
done
```

For each file `$f` containing digits in current directory, the `grep` command search in `names.txt` for a string `name` followed by the value of `$f` without potential leading zero: `"${f#0}"`.

If the string is found, the `mv` command renames the file with the desired name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a safe version of the solution - assumes the files to rename are in srcdir - it creates the renamed files in a new destdir directory - remove the echo for the actual copy - you can change cp to mv after verifying correct renaming

```
mkdir destdir
ls srcdir|paste - names.txt|
while read srcf destf; do
   echo cp srcdir/$srcf destdir/$destf
done
```